# ViewChild: ERROR TypeError: "this.child is undefined"

Tags: angular, core-ui

In Angular 7, I have a component that has a child component. However, I want to acquire a copy of that child component to use in the parent, to call its functions or whatever.

Child Component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
    <h1>child</h1>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
       name = "child";
       constructor(){}
}
```

Parent Component :

```
import { ChildComponent } from  './table/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <h1>parent</h1>
    <app-child></app-child>
  `,
})
export class  ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit{
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
   console.log(' ngAfterViewInit() : ', this.child.name);
  }

}
```

I'm using actually a template CoreUi https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-angular-admin-template, this template is different because for every component should have its own ( module and route ) .

**Child Component : `src/App/views/test/table/child.component.ts`**

**Parent Component : `src/App/views/test/parent.component.ts`**

could help me please to solve this issue,

Thank You

Comment: Will you share you html code too please?

Comment: Your code is correct but I think your child component is not loaded yet I need to see the your HTML code.

Comment: If @debabrata-paul-chowdhury is correct, try using `setTimeout(() => console.log(' ngAfterViewInit() : ', this.child.name),500)`. There are some situations, depending on where your child component is being instantiated (for example, in a dilagog and your child is dynamic instantated) that demands a longer wait. If this is your case, `setTimeout` will be enough and you can calibrate its delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine this is because the child component has not yet rendered, you could use [ngAfterContentInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterContentInit).

This lifecycle hook should only be fired once the child has been drawn, you should then be able to gain reference.

```
import { ChildComponent } from  './table/child.component';

export class  ParentComponent implements ngAfterContentInit, OnInit{
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;

   ngAfterContentInit(){
   console.log(' ngAfterContentInit() : ', this.child.name);
  }

}
```

Let me know if this is of any help.

Comment: thank for your help, but actually, it doesn't work solve my problem. because when I try it I got the same error !!

Comment: I didn't know yet how too, but I'm trying to look around the structure of this template where it comes to the problem I think. please, can u give any suggestion that can help me to solve it

Comment: after modifying the module of itself, your solution has been worked correctly thank you mate.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that you child was loaded, use `ViewChildren()`, and subscribe to the changes.